# Wait for first Tapped event to finish, then fire off the rest?

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to use tapped events to call and wait for one event to finish and then call the rest?

Ok, that sounds weird but an example will clear it up.

A user taps an item in a scroll and it should scroll into view first then call the remaining tapped events on that item in the scroller.

How do I capture the event before any of the item events are fired?

I thought I could upon loading the scroller I have, manipulate the events on the scroll items. But I feel that isn't very flexible and can cause unforeseen issues.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your issue.After tapped event finished, fire off what? What the rest you mean here? What actual issue you met? With some code snippet may describe your issue more clearly.

Comment: Basically I want to ensure a specific tapped event starts and finishes first before the rest of the tapped events on a UIElement `Tapped`. Is there a way to do this? It would enable me to make more interesting UX designs.